# Including External File's Variables In PHP Class For Use In Adobe/Apache Flex Service

Tags: php, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Basically what I am trying to do is relocate the database access variables (username, password, etc) to an external php file then include that file in the services. So, here's my service code that I though would work:

```
<?php
/** Database Access Information */
class LoginService {
    require 'parameters.php';

var $accesstable = "access";
var $lastlogintable = "last_login";
var $loginhistorytable = "login_history";

var $connection;

/** The constructor initializes the connection to database. */

public function __construct() {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
                            $this->server,  
                            $this->username,  
                            $this->password, 
                            $this->databasename,
                            $this->port
                        );

    $this->throwExceptionOnError($this->connection);
}
```

Then here is the code I thought would work in the external file:

```
<?php

var $username = "root";
var $password = "";
var $server = "localhost";
var $port = "3306";
var $databasename = "User";

?>
```

But, alas, it no worky...
Dreamweaver keeps giving me a syntax error on the line:

```
require 'parameters.php';
```

Comment: What does "no wokry" mean.  What is the syntax error that Dreamweaver gives you?

Comment: Dreamweaver simply says: "There is a syntax error on line 4. Code hinting may not until you fix this error"

Answer (score 0):

Put require inside a method - class syntax does not permit any code inside class body (but you can include anything in method body).

```
public function __construct() {
    require 'parameters.php'; 
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(
                        $this->server,  
                        $this->username,  
                        $this->password, 
                        $this->databasename,
                        $this->port
                    );

        $this->throwExceptionOnError($this->connection);
}
```

Comment: Well, that moved the syntax error to the second line of the parameters.php file...

Comment: Of course, "var" is defined only in body class. You must remove var from parameters.php - in a file you just initialise a variable... a usage according to my post would be mysql_connect($server) inside constructor method.

Comment: Thanks Antonis for your help here. I made the changes, and the syntax errors disappeared. However, on execution, I get "Notice: Undefined property: LoginService::$server in C:\wamp\www\dev\services\LoginService.php on line 16" which is "$this->server,"